# ¿Cómo eliminar punto duplicado en texto sin quitar el primero?

Tags: python-3.x

Deseo remover ".50" y que el resultado quede: "40.90"

```
texto = "40.90.50"
```

replace sí lo hace de izquierda a derecha pero no me sirve, deseo hacerlo de derecha a izquierda.

```
resul = texto.replace('.',  '', 1) """  1 remueve el primer punto. Print: Resultado: 4090.50
                                        2 remueve los 2 puntos.    Print: Resultado: 409050
```

¿Cómo le hago para que borre el segundo punto y los caracteres siguientes y que dé: 40.90?

```
print(resul)

    4090.50
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes separar el texto con `split()` por los puntos y luego volver a juntarlo, pero solo usando los 2 primeros elementos:

```python
print('.'.join('40.90.50'.split('.')[:2])) # 40.90
print('.'.join('192.168.0.120'.split('.')[:2])) # 192.168
print('.'.join('110'.split('.')[:2])) # 110
```

Comment: Super!! Saludos cordiales. ;)

Comment: Esta solución podría optimizarse más usando el argumento maxsplit=2. Esto indica que solo queremos separar la cadena en maximo en maxsplit + 1 partes. Esto ahorra iteraciones internas al cohete.

Answer (score 2):

Si todos tus casos son como el que muestras lo mas simple es usar `str.rsplit`, limitar a una las particiones y quedarte con el primer elemento de la lista:

```
texto = "40.90.50"
resultado = texto.rsplit(".", 1)[0]
```

Esto eliminara el ultimo punto y todo lo que exista a la derecha del mismo, independientemente del numero de puntos que existan antes. Si existe la posibilidad de que algunos casos tengan solo un punto o ninguno, entonces mejor usa `split` como muestra la respuesta de aeportugal.

Comment: Buena!! Saludos cordiales!!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la función `split` de la siguiente manera:

```
texto = "40.90.50"
partes = texto.split('.')
resul = '.'.join([partes[0], partes[1]])
print(resul)
```

Lo que hace `split` es almacenar en una lista cada elemento separado por un punto, dando como resultado `[40, 90, 50]`, luego en la variable `resul` hacemos un `join` con el primer elemento de tu lista y después con el segundo uniendolos con un punto **'.'** dando como resultado **40.90**.

Comment: Excelente!! Saludos cordiales. ;)